# Basic Derivation Work Check

Tags: logic

I'm just checking my work to make sure I'm going through this in a sane fashion, let me know if there is anything that is unclear, or if there are any suggestions (better solutions/ways to format better, sorry in advance for poor formatting, I'm not sure how to use LaTeX tables within stack exchange):

$P\wedge (Q\wedge R), S\rightarrow T, --S, (T\wedge Q) \rightarrow (U \wedge V)\vdash V$

Scope | Step | Derivation | Rule

1 | (1) |$P\wedge (Q\wedge R)$ | $A$

2 | (2) |$S\rightarrow T$ | $A$

3 | (3) |$--S$ | $A$

4 | (4) |$(T\wedge Q) \rightarrow (U\wedge V)$ | $A$

1 | (5) |$Q\wedge R$ | $1\wedge E$

1 | (6) |$Q$ | $5\wedge E$

3 | (7) |$S$| $3--E$

2,3 | (8) |$T$ | $2,7\rightarrow E$

1,2,3 | (9) |$T\wedge Q$ | $7,8\wedge I$

1,2,3,4 | (10) |$U\wedge V$ | $4,9\rightarrow E$

4 | (11) |$V$| $10\wedge E$

Thanks!

Comment: The deduction looks correct to me, but I'm not sure what the "scope" is supposed to mean - is that which assumptions each line relies on? If so, should the scope of line 11 not be 1, 2, 3, 4?

Comment: You're probably right about that, as the derivation of V goes beyond just it's own assumption. Thanks!